# jQuery UI Slider Event Firing During Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am using a jquery.ui slider on a webpage in order to navigate a jquery.flot graph which has too much data to be displayed at once.

I want the graph to update with every step the slider takes, and this works fine if the user grabs the handle and slides it his/herself. However, when they click somewhere on the slider the handle animates but the graph simply updates immediately to the point they clicked. I would like the graph to gradually update as the animation progresses.

Is this possible?

I am using the slide and change events to handle the graph update:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {shiftGraph(ui.value)},
    slide: function(event, ui) {shiftGraph(ui.value)},
    max: pastResults['json'].length-10,
    min: 0,
    animate: 'slow',
});
```